# Handle callback urls in Vue router

Tags: vue.js, auth0, vue-router, stamplay

I use Stamplay as BaaS, so to authenticate user, I just redirect to

> /auth/v1/auth0/connect

After, user authenticate.. the Stamplay call my app with

> /login/callback?jwt=abc.123.xyz

How can I authenticate user after Stamplay call my app?

### Tried

I my router config I try..

```
'/login/callback': {
  component: Vue.extend({
    ready() {
      // ...  THIS IS NOT CALLED!! NEVER
      console.log('... ready .. ')
      console.log(this.$route.query.jwt)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: If its about getting the query params please refer this: http://router.vuejs.org/en/route.html and also see how to implement authentication usually in vue.js. This is a good article here: https://auth0.com/blog/build-an-app-with-vuejs/. Now in your case your login component can always use the value it receives in the query-params and store in the local-storage and set the authentication flag in your app.

Comment: HI @Deepak, this article use [lock](https://auth0.com/lock) form, in my case, i call externall url that authenticate user and call my with with `/login/callback?jwt=xyz`

Comment: So, when call my Vue app (using URL `/login/callback?jwt=xyz`) I need to execute my code... to capture query string and set authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to access `this.$route.query.jwt` from within the component.

Comment: Yes, where else ? :) Could you provide a JSFiddle ? You can access it in your component, on `ready` event for instance

Comment: As stated in the comment by @Deepak , check http://router.vuejs.org/en/route.html . It states "The route object will be injected into every component in a vue-router-enabled app as this.$route" and `this.$route.query.jwt` should contain the value of the jwt you get back from Stamplay

Comment: Hi @kartsims, sorry for delay.  Yep. `this.$router` is injected into every component. But, how capture in router? Se my edited question.

Comment: OK but a fiddle would _really_ help me help you here

Comment: I create a github repo..  https://github.com/Ridermansb/vuex-router-auth0-example

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you will have a `view` component for `/login/callback` in your router config. what you need is when this component is activated, trigger some function right?

So in above view component, where you have `data`, `methods`, you can try to do this:

```
//your component
'/login/callback': {
  component: Vue.extend({
  data(){
    return {
    }
  },
  methods: {},
  route: {
    activate(){
      console.log('... ready .. ')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: follow the error. `vue.common.js?e881:2611 [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined. `